# How to Embed a Hyperlink - Django app

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm pretty much new to web development using Django, python, html, I've created have a basic Django app that displays a list of users from mysql, and all works just fine. I now want to make it so that user can click on the return value such as total books by users, date, etc.. is a link that when clicked on  will redirect to other page and displays the detail of that query, hopefully someone can walk me through..Thanks in advance..

```
# here I get all counter I need and it works just fine
def _get__user_info(self, qs):
    user.data['total_book']
    self._get_all_count(mydata, "total")
```

Comment: Can you explain more about what do you want?

Comment: What I have in mind is to . have hyperlink , or just make the link to the value I get from "self._get_all_count(mydata, "total"),